# How to parse 802.1q triple tagged frames using Scapy?

Tags: parsing, scapy, vlan

**Background:**

I'm working with `scapy` to parse `IEEE 802.1Q triple tagged frames`.  I'm generating test frames using scapy and capturing them to a pcap file.
The parsing is done in a separate script by reading in the pcap file.  I can successfully work with the 1st 802.1q tag.

**Problem:**

It's not clear to me how to access at the 2nd and 3rd 802.1q tags.  I'm attempting to use `haslayer()` and `getlayer` to conditionally examine the frame headers.  `haslayer(Dot1Q)` returns the 
values associated with the 1st Dot1Q tag.

**Question:**

If the `type` field of the 1st tag is `0x8100`, then a 2nd tag is present.  Is there a way to advance to the 2nd and 3rd tags?  I've looked at the l2.py source and experimented, but no luck yet.

**Code:**

Send triple tag frame:

```
    sendp(Ether(dst='78:2B:CB:33:4B:9F',src="D4:AE:52:89:BA:FA")/Dot1Q(vlan=1,id=3,prio=2)/Dot1Q(vlan=2,id=3,prio=2)/Dot1Q(vlan=3,id=3,prio=2)/IP(dst='10.25.222.222')/ICMP())
```

Frame display:

```
###[ Ethernet ]###
  dst       = 78:2b:cb:33:4b:9f
  src       = d4:ae:52:89:ba:fa
  type      = 0x8100
###[ 802.1Q ]###
     prio      = 2L
     id        = 1L
     vlan      = 1L
     type      = 0x8100
###[ 802.1Q ]###
        prio      = 2L
        id        = 1L
        vlan      = 2L
        type      = 0x8100
###[ 802.1Q ]###
           prio      = 2L
           id        = 1L
           vlan      = 3L
           type      = 0x800
###[ IP ]###
              version   = 4L
              ihl       = 5L
              tos       = 0x0
              len       = 28
              id        = 1
              flags     = 
              frag      = 0L
              ttl       = 64
              proto     = icmp
              chksum    = 0xc55
              src       = 10.25.123.123
              dst       = 10.25.222.222
              \options   \
###[ ICMP ]###
                 type      = echo-request
                 code      = 0
                 chksum    = 0xf7ff
                 id        = 0x0
                 seq       = 0x0
###[ Padding ]###
                    load      = '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Frame parsing:

```
pkts=rdpcap(self.file_name)

for pkt in pkts:

    try:
        if pkt.haslayer(Ether):
            src     = pkt.getlayer(Ether).src
            dst     = pkt.getlayer(Ether).dst
            type    = pkt.getlayer(Ether).type
            # Do something 

        if pkt.haslayer(Dot1Q):
            prio    = pkt.getlayer(Dot1Q).prio
            id      = pkt.getlayer(Dot1Q).id
            vlan    = pkt.getlayer(Dot1Q).vlan
            type    = pkt.getlayer(Dot1Q).type
            # Do something

    except:
        raise `
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the inner `802.1Q` tags of `pkt` with `pkt[Dot1Q:2]`, `pkt[Dot1Q:3]` and so on. If the packet doesn't have the specified layer, an appropriate `IndexError` exception is raised:

```
In [3]: pkt
Out[3]: <Ether  dst=78:2B:CB:33:4B:9F src=D4:AE:52:89:BA:FA type=0x8100 |<Dot1Q  prio=2 id=3 vlan=1 type=0x8100 |<Dot1Q  prio=2 id=3 vlan=2 type=0x8100 |<Dot1Q  prio=2 id=3 vlan=3 type=0x800 |<IP  frag=0 proto=icmp dst=10.25.222.222 |<ICMP  |>>>>>>

In [4]: pkt[Dot1Q:1]
Out[4]: <Dot1Q  prio=2 id=3 vlan=1 type=0x8100 |<Dot1Q  prio=2 id=3 vlan=2 type=0x8100 |<Dot1Q  prio=2 id=3 vlan=3 type=0x800 |<IP  frag=0 proto=icmp dst=10.25.222.222 |<ICMP  |>>>>>

In [5]: pkt[Dot1Q:2]
Out[5]: <Dot1Q  prio=2 id=3 vlan=2 type=0x8100 |<Dot1Q  prio=2 id=3 vlan=3 type=0x800 |<IP  frag=0 proto=icmp dst=10.25.222.222 |<ICMP  |>>>>

In [6]: pkt[Dot1Q:3]
Out[6]: <Dot1Q  prio=2 id=3 vlan=3 type=0x800 |<IP  frag=0 proto=icmp dst=10.25.222.222 |<ICMP  |>>>

In [7]: pkt[Dot1Q:4]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-a155defcb885> in <module>()
----> 1 pkt[Dot1Q:4]

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy_real-2.2.0_dev-py2.7.egg/scapy/packet.pyc in __getitem__(self, cls)
    770             elif type(lname) is not str:
    771                 lname = repr(lname)
--> 772             raise IndexError("Layer [%s] not found" % lname)
    773         return ret
    774 

IndexError: Layer [Dot1Q] not found
```

Of course, you may check the type value and only after verifying that it is `0x8100`, try accessing the inner layer.